# Change autosave url parameter after success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using the autosave plugin (below) to save form automatically when field changes
http://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/using-the-jquery-autosave-plugin/

When the form is first loaded the form id is zero ("0"). I save the form change successfully and request the database id...What I'm trying to do is to get that new id and apply it to the url of the autosave so when the next change occurs it uses that id to save to database.

I have tried to make another ajax call to update the page with new id but the page replacement it's not good.  I honestly don't know why the variable won't change. and the url update...My preference is to use what I have and change the url on the autosave successfully.

```
fid = "<?php echo json_encode($formid);?>";

function setDefault(formID){
    fid=formID;
}

furl="autosave.php?formname=" + aformname;

$("input,select,textarea,radio,checkbox").not('.SaveBtn').autosave({
    url: furl + "&id=" + fid,    //set the php file to update the database
    method: "POST",
    grouped: true,                                          
    success: function(data) {                                       
            var formID= data.replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g, '');
            if(formID){
                    setDefault(formID);
            }
    },
    send: function(){//on a save...
            $("#message").html("Sending data....");//..show a message
    },
    dataType:"html"
});
```

I've been stuck on this for 2 days now.

Comment: Just at a glance, I see that your `furl` string is formatted incorrectly. Try this: `furl = "autosave.php?formname=" + aformname;`

Comment: you are right it's not right here! Updated...but I do have it right on my code.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem if anybody else needs to do something like it. 
After the first field was successful in the database, the form id was stored in a hidden field.
On the next field change, the autosave plugin will take the hidden value and the changes will be stored to the right form ID.

```
$("input,select,textarea,radio,checkbox").not('.SaveBtn').autosave({
    url: furl,    //set the php file to update the database
    method: "POST",
    grouped: true,                                          
    success: function(data) {                                       
        var formID= data.replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g, '');
        if(formID){
                $("#hiddenformid").val(formID);
        }
      },
   send: function(){//on a save...
        $("#message").html("Sending data....");//..show a message
    },
    dataType:"html"
    });

 <input type="hidden" name="hiddenformid" id="hiddenformid" value="<?php echo $formid;?>">
```